# What´s a good practice for accessing external configurations in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, components, singleton

I´m setting up a Spring Boot application where certain configurations are being read from my application.yaml-file. I´ve done this a few times before and it works well, but I wondered whether there is a better way to access this configuration during runtime or whether I´m creating possible issues by not following some best practice.

Right now the class that extracts the configuration is simply defined as a Component like this:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("myPrefix")
public class MyExternalConfiguration{
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> entries= new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    public Boolean getConfigurationForKey(String key) {
        return this.entries.get(key);
    }
}
```

And then autowired to several other classes that need to access this configuration like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClass{
    @Autowired
    private MyExternalConfiguration myExternalConfiguration;

    public void doSomething(){
        //...
        Boolean someEntry = myExternalConfiguration.getConfigurationForKey(someKey);
    }
}
```

Now, this does work just fine. It´s just that I have seen examples of where configurations like this are handled as a singleton for example (although not in a Spring-Boot environment). I would just like to ask, whether there is some commonly accepted way to access external configurations or whether you see an issue with the way i access it in my project.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole chapter about configuration in the Spring Boot Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Simply said there are two options to access configuration:

With the Value annotation:

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;
```

Or typesafe with a configuration class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

So there is no need to read the configuration file by your own.

Comment: Uhmm.... but isn't the second snipped you write exactly what I do? It does require the specific class. My question is about how to best access the member of said class that did the reading.

Comment: No the second snipped is a class that you will inject and that has getters for all configuration properties. It's typesafe not a map with some keys like in your example